# How do you set txindex to 1?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, txindex

I am using bitcoin.rpc.RawProxy to connect to bitcoind and scrape the data. But I am getting an error when I `gettransaction` and I have to reindex the blockchain. Thus I am wondering how I set the txindex to 1 so I can reindex and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the `txindex` by either adding it to your `bitcoin.conf` file:

```
txindex=1
```

or

You can run `bitcoind` with the `-txindex` flag:

```
$ bitcoind -txindex
```

See:

```
$ bitcoind --help

    -txindex
       Maintain a full transaction index, used by the getrawtransaction rpc
       call (default: 0)
```

Comment: but reindexing is necessary correct?

Comment: Yes you might need to also use the `-reindex` flag. You might also want to set a higher `-dbcache` to speed it up.

Comment: One more question, and thanks again. If I do not shut out of the ubuntu command prompt correctly, for example if I have to restart it or if it shuts down unexpectedly, can it corrupt the data?

Comment: And will I know if the database is corrupted? For example, will the program notify me?

Comment: If you set the `-daemon` flag it will run in the background and you can close the terminal. If it shuts down, it may corrupt the data, but you should see errors in `~/.bitcoin/debug.log`

Comment: would I have to run the file `debug.log` or just click into it? Basically how would I tell?

Comment: it is a text file, but I think the application will crash if the data is corrupted. Either way, you can watch the log file with `$ tail -f ~/.bitcoin/debug.log`